# jQuery Function Returning NaN

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I've managed to use jQuery to retrieve an age from a birthdate, but I'm running into some issues. Using the code below, the script works if there is only one span to retrieve. Leaving the second half of spans uncommented gives me NaN.

```
<span class="dob">8/21/1997</span>
<span class="subtext">Age: <span class="age"></span></span>
<span class="dob">5/10/2001</span>
<span class="subtext">Age: <span id="age"></span></span>

function buildData() {
    var years = moment().diff($(".dob").text(), "years", false);
      function calcAge() {
        $(".age").text(years)
        }
     window.onload = calcAge();
}
window.onload = buildData();
```

Here, the list of birthdates is hard-coded, but in practice it's coming from an array echoed from a database. The number of birthdates listed can vary depending on certain factors. I'm assuming that I need to loop through this somehow, but cannot for the life of me understand how to do that for both "dob" and "age", keeping them together. Any pointers would be most welcome.

Comment: Even with only one of those, I don't get any results. `Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. ` warning from Moment

Comment: Moment's documentation lists out the supported formats: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/. If you're going to do a MM-DD-YYYY format it might be best to add formatting information https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: you are comparing a date, which is moment(), with text, which is $(".dob").text(). You need to use something like moment().diff(moment($(".dob").text()))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the date format would be having issues, but I'll look further into the moment documentation. I wasn't able to resolve the jQuery side and decided to use this PHP bit to calculate the age from the birth year, since I'd already retrieved the info from the database and put it into an array.

> echo date_diff(date_create($bDayRow['birthdate']),
> date_create('today'))->y ;